# Redirect ffmpeg showinfo (only) to pipe while keeping other output on stderr

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using `ffmpeg` to help with processing video by breaking it down into smaller regions which are then piped to my program for processing.

I run `ffmpeg` like so:

```
ffmpeg \
    -y \
    -ss 2841000000us \
    -to 2843000000us \
    -i "<INPUT_URL>" \
    -fps_mode passthrough \
    -an \
    -filter_complex "[v:0]fps=fps=4[t1];[t1]showinfo[out1];[out1]split=4[out2][out3][out4][out5];[out5]crop=711:10:1044:90[out9];[out4]crop=711:10:165:90[out8];[out3]crop=73:63:1764:964[out7];[out2]crop=73:63:82:964[out6]" \
    -map [out6] -c:v bmp -f image2pipe "\\.\pipe\ofl_80ff20228c90467e89709bd8052b572a" \
    -map [out7] -c:v bmp -f image2pipe "\\.\pipe\ofl_0585f9807eef4b1397075ef4aabf9fd1" \
    -map [out8] -c:v bmp -f image2pipe "\\.\pipe\ofl_fe0eba9becbd488fb9f09e1c7c479eb7" \
    -map [out9] -c:v bmp -f image2pipe "\\.\pipe\ofl_6f03f63dd4a6435eb4a3e45017528ec0"
```

This works great, and I'm able to get the frames that I'm looking for.

Additionally, it outputs the timestamp info for each frame.

However, I'm looking for a way to output the contents of `showinfo` (and *only* `showinfo`) to something I can pick up in my program.

It is currently redirecting to stderr, but it gets intermingled with other information, which I'd rather read and keep separate (in the event of an error, etc.).

Is there a way that I can direct the bytes/output of `showinfo` (and *only* `showinfo`) to a named pipe (windows or unix is fine, doesn't matter)?

Comment: Not possible. showinfo readouts are sent to the logger only. I'll work on a patch to change that when I have time.